# java.util.logging and log4j

Tags: jboss, log4j, java.util.logging

My application is already using Java.Util logging and I don't have control over changing it to **SLF4J**. It is deployed to JBoss 5.1 and I need to control the log level of the messages. In java.util.logging the levels are different than log4j.

I have below in my source code.

`logger.log(Level.FINE,"a debug level message")`

`...`

`logger.log(Level.INFO,"info level message")`

Currently it shows the INFO level message in System.out and my jboss-log4j.xml looks like below. If I needed to show the **debug** level message how should I be changing the jboss-log4j.xml ?

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: `<param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>` not working for you?

Comment: No. I tried that and I don't see the debug level message

Comment: can you post the full log4j.xml file, or at leats the general setup in there to see if there is a global threshold whoch overrides the appender value.